# Richardson extrapolation and improvement in error

Tags: numerical-methods

I am using the Simpson's composite rule for evaluating integrals, this is $O(h^4)$, where $h$ is the step size. We can use the Richardson's trick to improve things (I denote the integral to be evaluated by $f_I$):

$$\frac{16}{15}S(\frac{1}{2}h)-\frac{1}{15}S(h)=f_I+C\frac{16}{15}(\frac{1}{2}h)^4-C\frac{1}{15}h^4+O(h^5)=f_I+O(h^5) $$

Ok, so the order of error improved by one. But yet when I actually run the imrpoved algorithm the error of order always increases by 2 so that it goes towards $1/64$ on each halving, up from $1/16$. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your integrand is sufficiently differentiable, then Simpson's rule obeys an asymptotic error expansion of the form
$$ I - S_h = \alpha h^4 + \beta h^6  + O(h^8), \quad h \rightarrow 0, \quad h > 0.$$
Richardson extrapolation $$R_h = S_h + \frac{S_h - S_{2h}}{15}$$ eliminates the primary error term, i.e., the term $\alpha h^4$ and satisfies an asymptotic error expansion of the form
$$ I - R_h = \beta' h^6 + O(h^8) , \quad h \rightarrow 0, \quad h > 0.$$
The fact that your are observing orders of convergence which are $4$ for Simpson's rule and $6$ for the extrapolated rule is a strong indication that your integrand is many differentiable.

Comment: Good answer, is there a chance you could expand upon what is meant by sufficiently differentiable? In particular, Is the general derivation of the Simpson's rule already this way or do we need something more?

Comment: I recall that for Simpson's rule to be $O(h^4)$ the function has to already be 4 times differentiable.

Comment: It should be $16S_h-S_{2h}$. @Tony : Yes, to get the 6th order error behavior the function needs to be 6 times differentiable. With some effort one could reduce this to 5 times continuously differentiable, as the leading error term can be expressed as an integral over the 6th derivative. Note that Simpson is already the Richardson extrapolation of the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Great! Do you have a source for why the error behaves this way? Also, is there some easy example of a function that is exactly 4 times (continuously?) differentiable.

Comment: @Tony : Because the quadrature method is time symmetric there can be no odd error term. Functions of the form $x^m|x|$ are exactly $m$ times continuously differentiable in $x=0$.